# Dynamic annotation configuration settings in BRAT

Tags: python, annotations, nlp, brat

In [Brat](http://brat.nlplab.org/), to annotate a text you should refer to a single configuration file called 'annotation.conf', I have more than 150 tags to annotate semantics of domain-specific text and **these annotation tags should be separated in different configuration files** so the annotators won't get distracted to select from a long list  if all the tags are stored in a single 'annotation.conf' file.

A typical scenario would be, the annotator will upload a text then for each statement there are certain keywords which should trigger a single annotation.conf file from the groups I created to organise my semantic tags.

Let's take the following pseudo example:

- Statement: A **KB** C  ===> should trigger annotation.conf for they
  keyword **KB**
- Statement: V N C **KA** ====> should trigger annotation.conf for the
  keyword **KA**

There is NO overlapping between the tags .i.e. each word(s) should be labelled by a single tag only.

Would you please guide me how I can achieve this in BRAT, referring to specific resources is really appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot trigger different configuration files via keywords in Brat. However, you can organise your tag list into a tree hierarchy, which should hopefully help reduce confusion in your annotators. You can see how to do that [here](http://brat.nlplab.org/configuration.html#annotation-configuration).

Alternately, if you can sort your "statements" by the keyword into different files, and upload those different files in different directories, each directory can have its own `annotation.conf`.

Comment: Thank on your reply. I assume this is the only choice to resolve my problem.